# Android apktool error

Tags: android, apk, android-install-apk

Hi my customer tried to add the apk to their market application and an error occured like below.

*18.Ağu.2011 12:23:14 brut.androlib.res.AndrolibResources loadMainPkg INFO: Loading resource table... Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Androlib Error: Multiple resources: spec=0x7f02004c drawable/top_bar_large, config=-ldpi*

it seems the tool thinks that the drawable resource named top_bar_large has been used more than once. That's right but in different drawable directories.

I mean the image is located in the directories;

drawable-ldpi

drawable-xlarge-ldpi

As I know android handles this automatically. And I also have installed that failing (actually the tool thinks it is failing) apk to my phones and other phones ( different brand ) without any issue !

What do I need to do ? can you help me ?

Comment: You probably need to help them to get a better apktool for their market. If it works as expected on phones and on the market and in eclipse and it's logical but doesn't work for their market...the problem probably comes from their market !

Amazon app market for instance has limitations on version name for apks. sirandroid (for turkey) never accepted my apk files without detailling why and support did not find time to answer since last month... Briefly, it happens that market side sofwares are not so mature.

Comment: thank you very much. I have tested the apk for 2 phones. also customer tested it with aolmost 20 different devices. and now they returned like this !!

Answer (score 2):

I hope this is still relevant.

I would suggest one of two things. First, try the latest version of apktool. As far as I know, xlarge was added rather late to apktool. The latest version *should* work fine.

If not, you can try [zzos](https://github.com/Shachar/Lingnu-Android-Tools) (full disclosure: zzos was written by me). It is much less known, but may occasionally be able to handle APKs that apktool fails to decompile. In particular, I happen to know that xscale is supported by zzos, and has been for some time.

I hope this helps,
Shachar

Comment: the problem was solved by customer. so this is not relevant anymore. issue was with their configuration parameters.